# Filter datatable or excel(delete rows) when certain range(C:N) of column has zero value c#

Tags: c#, excel, datatable

I read an excel and converted to datatable.
I am trying to filter datatable by deleting rows when column range C:N contains zero. Here is my code

```
using (var package = new ExcelPackage(file.InputStream))
    {
        var currentSheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets;
        var workSheet = currentSheet.First();
        var noOfCol = workSheet.Dimension.End.Column;
        var noOfRow = workSheet.Dimension.End.Row;

        bool hasHeader = true;

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        foreach (var firstRowCell in workSheet.Cells[2, 1, 1, workSheet.Dimension.End.Column])
        {
            dt.Columns.Add(hasHeader ? firstRowCell.Text : string.Format("Column {0}", firstRowCell.Start.Column));
        }

        for (int rowNum = 3; rowNum <= noOfRow; rowNum++)
        {
            var wsRow = workSheet.Cells[rowNum, 1, rowNum, workSheet.Dimension.End.Column];
            DataRow row = dt.Rows.Add();
            foreach (var cell in wsRow)
            {
                if (null == cell.Value)
                    row[cell.Start.Column - 1] = 0;
                else
                    row[cell.Start.Column - 1] = cell.Value;
            }


        }

        var rows = dt.Select("HF=0  AND HAI=0 AND HCAS=0 AND HUND=0 AND TCF=0 AND MW=0 AND TR=0 AND PCH=0 AND NUT=0 AND PAC=0 AND HLA=0 AND NAV=0");                                      
        foreach (var row in rows)
        { row.Delete(); }
        dt.AcceptChanges();
    }
```

Below is the screenshot of my datatable

[image]

Datatable has column range from A:N.

My requirement is to filter this datatable by deleting rows when column range C:N contains zero.

Below is code which I am using to filter datatable based on column header

```
    var rows = dt.Select("HF=0  AND HAI=0 AND HCAS=0 AND HUND=0 AND TCF=0 AND MW=0 AND TR=0 AND PCH=0 AND NUT=0 AND PAC=0 AND HLA=0 AND NAV=0");                                      
                                            foreach (var row in rows)
                                            { row.Delete(); }
dt.AcceptChanges();
```

Error that I am facing is

> Cannot perform '=' operation on System.String and System.Int32.

I made all the values as numeric before reading excel file, but still facing error.

Filter approach which I am using is working when datatable has few records example 30, but is failing when more than 400 records.

Unable to trace where I am going wrong.
Can someone suggest a better approach if I am doing something wrong.

I also tried to filter worksheet but it fails. that's the reason why I am doing based on datatable. If there is worksheet solution, please let me know.

Comment: Your Excel file contains `"0"`s, not `0`s.

Comment: @GSerg Could you please let me how did you identify whether it is 0 or "0"

Comment: Because they are left-aligned.

Answer (score 0):

By changing below 2 conditions I was able to get desired result.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 14; i++)
      {
        if (null == wsRow[rowNum, i].Value)
          row[i - 1] = "0";
        else
          row[i - 1] = wsRow[rowNum, i].Value.ToString();
       }

var rows = dt.Select("HF='0'  AND HAI='0' AND HCAS='0' AND HUND='0' AND TCF='0' AND MW='0' AND TR='0' AND PCH='0' AND NUT='0' AND PAC='0' AND HLA='0' AND NAV='0'");
```